# Global redirect edit link

Tags: 6, redirection

I am using the global redirect module. This makes `/node/1` goes to my path auto `/node/clean-title`. If I goto `/node/clean-title/edit` I get a 404 error. If I go to `/node/1/edit.` How can I get it so that `/node/clean-title/edit` works. I would like this to happen on all my nodes automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [Subpath Alias](http://drupal.org/project/subpath_alias) module.

> For example, if node/1 is aliased to
>   content/alias, this module rewrites
>   the link to the node edit page
>   node/1/edit to use the aliased URL
>   content/alias/edit instead.

Comment: GAAARRR - doesn't exist for Drupal 7!

Answer (score 1):

By default, path auto only supports node display urls. You could create a small custom module that integrates with path auto and creates the edit urls as as well.

The easiest thing to do, is probably to look at the path auto module and see how it does it. You should be able to copy/paste a lot of code and add `/edit` where needed to make it work for node edit urls as well.